# Issues with displaying Alerts in Swift (After clicking "Ok", it unwinds segue

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I wrote the following function below to display alerts through my project. Every time i check for an error in a form i display the alert when the user clicks submit. I want to simply show the alert, but not unwind the pervious segue. I want to stay at the current screen and give the user the opportunity to complete the form. Right now when the user clicks submit, it displays the alert ..but when i click the ok button to dismiss the alert it immediately unwinds the segue to the previous screen.

I have included the UIAlertViewDelegate in the class.... any ideas why this might be happening?

```
func displayAlert(title:String, error:String) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: only remove self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) in your code it will not dismiss your view. see [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/)

Comment: yeah it literally just hit me. I was thinking too hard! lol

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

func displayAlert(title:String, error:String) {

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in
   //comment out this line and it will still work. It will not segue back to the previous screen. 
    //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}